# How to change the thickness of a circle with css?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have the following design made with html and css, as you will see the circle looks somewhat thick, its outline.

[image]

This design is made as follows:

```css
    .fa-stack-1x, .fa-stack-2x {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .fa-stack-2x {
        font-size: 2em;
    }

    .size-icon-about {
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2 mb-r wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
         <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x icon-blue"></i>
         <i class="fa fa-briefcase size-icon-about icon-blue"></i>
        </span>
        <h3 class="text-body-about mt-3">Subtitle</h3>
    </div>
```

I'm basically using the following fontawesome icon: https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/circle-thin

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - the line thickness is built into the font and you can't change it. Fortunately, however, circles are easy to draw using pure HTML/CSS by employing `border-radius: 50%` and `border-width: <n>px` where `n` is the thickness of the line you want. You'll need to do some position tweaking to center the briefcase inside it. The only problem there is scaling - if you need the image to appear in multiple scales, you'll have to set the border thickness appropriately, and in that case, you may be forced back to an svg solution.

EDIT: I did find another way to 'cheat' - you may be able to use `text-stroke` to partially trim the font thickness, e.g.: `-webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;`

Comment: If it is integrated in the font is it possible to do it with font-weigth?

Comment: You can only use variants that exist - however see my edit above for another approach that may work for you if you have a fixed color background.

Answer (score 0):

Actually In this scenario you don't have option to reduce the stroke of the font icon. But we can adjust this using a fake method as shown below.

Here I removed the Icon circle and created my own. From `border` property you can adjust the border size of circle easily. This can be applied as a transparent icon.

### Method 1

```css
/* .fa-stack-1x, .fa-stack-2x {
  

bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
} */

.fa-stack-2x {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.size-icon-about {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #111111;
  position: relative;
}


.fa-briefcase {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="col-md-2 mb-r wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
     <span class="circle">
       <i class="fa fa-briefcase size-icon-about icon-blue"></i>
     </span>         
    </span>
    <h3 class="text-body-about mt-3">Subtitle</h3>
</div>
```

---

### Method 2

Here I have created another `<span class="circle">` which is positioned absolute and change it's height and width values as we can see a thin border on icon circle. but this can't be applied as a transparent icon since our circle has a background color. For that, you need to set that `circle` background same as the section background which beneath the icon.

```css
/* .fa-stack-1x, .fa-stack-2x {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
} */

.fa-stack-2x {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.size-icon-about {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 77px;
  height: 77px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 10;
}

.fa-circle-thin {
  position: relative;
}

.fa-briefcase {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="col-md-2 mb-r wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
     <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x icon-blue">
       <span class="circle"></span>
     </i>
     <i class="fa fa-briefcase size-icon-about icon-blue"></i>
    </span>
    <h3 class="text-body-about mt-3">Subtitle</h3>
</div>
```